# Lombok @NonNull vs Validate.notNull

Tags: java, design-patterns, coding-style, lombok

I have class `XYZ` which have two functions.

```
ABC
DEF
```

`ABC` takes parameter `A`  and `B` and I need to perform only null check on `A` and `B`.

Currently I am using

```
ABC(@NonNull String A, @NonNull String B)
```

Similar way function DEF take function `D` and `E` but it need to perform extra validation check.

Is it good idea to mix `@NonNull` and `validator` ?

Comment: Actually it depends. There is no crystal-clear approach. You have pre-validation step and post-validation one. In such cases it could be the way to go with the approach as you've mentioned above. Also you could take a look at the experimental and workaround ways of doing different things in lombok: [lombok experimental](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX.html) Authors are still trying to 'we heard you like annotations, so we put annotations in your annotations so you can annotate while you're annotating.' :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would advocate consistency.

The reasoning is that while Lombok is an automatic code generator, it also uses annotations. Using the `@NonNull` annotation creates a certain expectation on the part of anyone reading code that input that absolutely must have a value that is not Null is annotated with `@NonNull`.